# Using pointers for 4 dimensional cube

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to print a 4D cube using `****` pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define DIM 4

void printCube(char ****cube, int dim) {
    int x, y, z;
    for (z = 0; z < dim; z++) {
        for (y = 0; y < dim; y++) {
            for (x = 0; x < dim; x++) {
                printf("%c ", *cube[z][y][x]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("------------------------------------\n");
    }
}

int main() {
    char ***cube = (char ***)malloc(sizeof(char **) * DIM);
    int x, y, z;
    for (z = 0; z < DIM; z++) {
        cube[z] = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char **) * DIM);
        for (y = 0; y < DIM; y++) {
            cube[z][y] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char *) * DIM);
            for (x = 0; x < DIM; x++) {
                cube[z][y][x] = ((x + y + z) % 26) + 'A';
            }
        }
    }

    printCube(&cube, DIM);

    for (z = 0; z < DIM; z++) {
        for (y = 0; y < DIM; y++) {
            for (x = 0; x < DIM; x++) {
                free(cube[z][y][x]);
            }
            free(cube[z][y]);
        }
        free(cube[z]);
    }
    free(cube);
    return 0;
}
```

I am sure the error is easy but I tried now for several hours to figure out.

Should be simply that I have to use the pointer at `printf` something else (because if I am printing only chars it is working fine)

```
printf("%c ", *cube[z][y][x]);
```

does someone have tips for me how to correct this code?

Really appreciate your support.

Comment: Whats the error that it throws?

Comment: Idea: Simplification to `cube = (char ***)malloc(sizeof(char **) * DIM);` --> `cube = malloc(sizeof *cube * DIM);`.  Likewise: `cube[z] = malloc(sizeof *size[z] * DIM); ....  cube[z][y] = malloc(sizeof *cube[z][y] * DIM);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- Your cube only has 3 dimensions, it is an ordinary cube represented as an array of pointers to arrays of pointers to arrays of `int`. Passing this array to the `printCube` function directly will actually pass a pointer to its first element, with type `int ***`. In your case, since the top-level array is allocated, you already have a pointer with type `int ***`. Thus the function prototype should be `void printCube(char ***cube, int dim)`. There is no reason to pass the address of the pointer instead of its value.
- You have some errors in the computation of the allocation sizes: `cube[z] = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char **) * DIM);` should be

  ```
  cube[z] = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *) * DIM);
  ```

  and `cube[z][y] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char *) * DIM);` should be

  ```
  cube[z][y] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * DIM);
  ```
- You should remove a level in your freeing loops as `cube[z][y][x]` is not an allocated pointer, but merely a character in the array pointed to by `cube[z][y]`. It is a shame that your compiler accept this code with a simple warning. You should use `gcc -Wall -Werror` to avoid such silly mistakes.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define DIM 4

void printCube(char ***cube, int dim) {
    int x, y, z;
    for (z = 0; z < dim; z++) {
        for (y = 0; y < dim; y++) {
            for (x = 0; x < dim; x++) {
                printf("%c ", cube[z][y][x]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("------------------------------------\n");
    }
}

int main() {
    char ***cube = (char ***)malloc(sizeof(char **) * DIM);
    int x, y, z;
    for (z = 0; z < DIM; z++) {
        cube[z] = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *) * DIM);
        for (y = 0; y < DIM; y++) {
            cube[z][y] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char ) * DIM);
            for (x = 0; x < DIM; x++) {
                cube[z][y][x] = ((x + y + z) % 26) + 'A';
            }
        }
    }

    printCube(cube, DIM);

    for (z = 0; z < DIM; z++) {
        for (y = 0; y < DIM; y++) {
            free(cube[z][y]);
        }
        free(cube[z]);
    }
    free(cube);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
A B C D
B C D E
C D E F
D E F G
------------------------------------
B C D E
C D E F
D E F G
E F G H
------------------------------------
C D E F
D E F G
E F G H
F G H I
------------------------------------
D E F G
E F G H
F G H I
G H I J
------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thx to all of you for your support. Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to take the address of `cube` when passing it to `printCube`.  Instead, just pass it directly, declare it as `char ***` in `printCube`, and then access it as `cube[z][y][x]` in `printCube`.

The way it is now, you're using `*cube[z][y][x]` in `printCube`, which doesn't work because `*` binds more loosely than `[]`.  It would work if you changed it to `(*cube)[z][y][x]`.  But as I said, there is no need for the extra level of indirection in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

You are a victim of operator precedence. In C, a post-fix operator is of higher precedence than a pre-fix operator. In your case, the prefix operator is `'*'` and the post-fix operator is `'[]'`

So, the expression:

```
*cube[z][y][x]
```

is equivalent to:

```
*(cube[z][y][x])
```

which is not desirable, because `cube[z][y][x]` is a pointer pointing to invalid memory, and attempting to use this pointer will cause undefined behavior.

You should first de-reference the `cube` pointer and then use the subscript operators:

```
(*cube)[z][y][x]
```

This fixes your problem. On the other hand, since you do not attempt to modify the value of `cube` pointer in the function and you are just using its value, you can simplify your function to take a `char ***`. Then you pass the `cube` pointer by value and you don't have to bother with operator precedence.